# Meteor build refresh after file change saving drops an EACCES error in a docker container

Tags: docker, meteor, docker-compose

### SUMMARY

First of all I run my Meteor web app using docker-compose with `docker-compose -f docker-file.dev.yml up -d --build`. Everything works fine **for the first build**. The app is reachable on my browser via localhost.

Then I have an **EACESS** error while I use my code editor (vscode) to edit some .jsx files, this runs the build refresh, then, the application, running in a docker container crashes. It means I have a permission error.
But, when I save an updated file, this is done with my current (windows) user into VSCode, anyway, the app is run by "meteoruser" user defined in the docker-compose.dev.yml file below.

So what is the problem with this configuration, it worked well on a previous computer running ubuntu 16.04. Is windows the problem?

If I check docker logs I have this output :

[image]

If I rerun docker-compose build command, then everything is fine, the files are updated and the app is running. But I can't work like that and rerun this command every time I make a file change.

What I expect is a build refresh working without dropping an **EACCESS** error.

### Additionnal informations about my project

This is a React project within Meteor framework in a container, using mongodb container within an nginx proxy in a container as well.

Project scaffold:

[image]

docker-compose file

[image]

docker file (.dev)

[image]

nb: as you can see, I create an user in the container, then I run the app into the container with this user. This is needed to ensure not running locally the app as root user.

### WHAT I HAVE  TRIED

1. Delete the .meteor folder and rebuild locally with `meteor run` to ensure my current windows user has the rights for the meteor app build folder. It do not work.
2. Remove the usage of meteoruser in the dockerfile, this does not work and instead drop an error, because meteor do not allow running app in a dev environment with root user, because it could lead to permission errors later in production..

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm curious: why do you want to run meteor in a docker container during development?

Comment: The environment was setup the same way, same processes for dev and prod, I think - it was a long time ago - that a library like facebook needed to have https and I wanted to see it working live in dev. I could have used nginx aside but it was simpler for me to make it work with the same docker workflow.

That said, I will try working without docker for dev, it is not needed for the changes I have to bring on this project.

Comment: In meteor the dev environment looks very different from production anyways, because things like hot-reload are of course not needed in production. So even if you use docker, you still won't have identical setups. The https part is definitely true though.

Comment: Yeah indeed, I think I'm gonna work without containers for local, I just need to link it to a mongodb or something .. Arf

Comment: meteor will start it's own mongodb instance if you don't set MONGO_URL.